# Dynamic text Field Color changing

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-cmd

I wanna chage the color of an ExtJs text Field, named filter, after the Input of a particular string for Example if I input 'type:' the tex color should change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ExtJS 6.0.1:

```
textfield.inputEl.setStyle("color", "#f00")
```

Comment: thanks Alexander you saved me whole lots of work was tryna replace the class with innerHTML.replace('',''), that did more harm of cause. thanks